# A better way to write this recursive function that finds an odd amount of numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, recursion

I made this recursive solution to find if a number is in an array an odd amount of times and if not return null.  I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for better cleaner code. Just trying to improve, Thanks!

```
let odd = [0, 5, 6, 6, 4, 0, 1, 5, 2, 4];
let j = 1;
let number;

function tryAgain(odd) {
  let counter = 0;

  odd.forEach((num, i, arr) => {
    if (num === arr[j]) {
      counter++;
      number = arr[j];
    }
  });
  if (counter > 1 && counter % 2 !== 0) {
    return number;
  } else {
    j++;
    if (j > odd.length) {
      number = null;
      return false;
    } else {
      tryAgain(odd);
    }
  }
  return number;
}
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved see [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the problem with a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), we can structure our program in a straightforward way -

1. if the input `t` is empty, there is nothing to count, return false
2. (by induction) the input is NOT empty. If the first element of `t` matches the query `q`, return the opposite of the recursive result
3. (by induction) the input is NOT empty and the first element of `t` does NOT match the query `q`. return the recursive result

```js
const oddCount = (t = [], q = null) =>
  t.length === 0
    ? false                      // 1
: t[0] === q
    ? !oddCount(t.slice(1), q)   // 2
: oddCount(t.slice(1), q)        // 3

const data =
  [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  
console.log
  ( oddCount(data, 1) // false
  , oddCount(data, 2) // true
  , oddCount(data, 3) // false
  , oddCount(data, 4) // true
  , oddCount(data, 9) // false
  )
```

There is an odd count of `2`s and `4`s in the `data` array. However `1`, `3`, and `9` do not have an odd count.